# Vaadin resources aren't loaded in OSGI

Tags: osgi, vaadin

I have a set of bundles I created with Maven + BND. One of the bundles contains my Vaadin "Application", the others have some utilities and additional editors.

I can run this app on a Tomat server - everything is OK. Then I tried running in OSGI (Apache Felix). After many solved problems I finally managed to run the OSGI runtime and have all the bundles loaded and activated correctly.
I can even access the 1st page with "localhost:8080/bat" - it does not show "404 not found" anymore.

The problem is: The start page only shows some **unformatted text** from my app.

the app can't load its Vaadin resources (CSS, maybe widgetset, etc). 
the debug frame says:

```
Starting Vaadin client side engine. Widgetset: com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet
Widget set is built on version: 6.6.6
Warning: widgetset version 6.6.6 does not seem to match theme version
Starting application bat-97301
Vaadin application servlet version: 6.6.6
Application version: 0.0.1
inserting load indicator
Making UIDL Request with params: init
Server visit took 9ms
...
Assuming CSS loading is not complete, postponing render phase. (.v-loading-indicator height == 0)
Assuming CSS loading is not complete, postponing render phase. (.v-loading-indicator height == 0)
....
CSS files may have not loaded properly.
```

looks like Vaadin resources can't be loaded.

**so, the question is:**
what's a proper structure for a Vaadin application packed as an OSGI bundle?

here's my OSGI bundle structure (created with Maven + BND):
(I skipped some Vaadin Reindeer theme folders as not important)

```
├───com
│   └───my
│       ├───demomodules
│       ├───preferences
│       ├───widgetset
│       └───workspaces
├───META-INF
├───VAADIN
│   ├───icons
│   ├───themes
│   │   ├───mytheme
│   │   └───reindeer
│   │       ├───a-sprite-definitions
│   └───widgetsets
│       ├───com.my.widgetset.Vaadin1Widgetset
│       │   └───ie6pngfix
│       └───WEB-INF
│           └───deploy
│               └───com.my.widgetset.Vaadin1Widgetset
│                   ├───rpcPolicyManifest
│                   └───symbolMaps
└───WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently did this exercise. Googling on vaadin and OSGi reveals that there are different takes on how to integrate and on which level, e.g. component or application. However, the key "realization point" is that you must arrange it so that the VAADIN resources are accessible from the client, i.e. can be served as resources from your "servlet". I don't think the bundle structure as such will help you here, you must deal with the Http Service and give it instructions on how to serve the stuff.

Take a look at the vaadin examples by neil bartlett at https://github.com/njbartlett/VaadinOSGi, specifcially the vaadinbridge project. That helped me in understanding the issues.

Another approach might be to deploy the bundle on an OSGi continer that understands WARs, such as Virgo. But that is just a guess.

Comment: a [hack-style] temporary solution I found is: declare your bundle with Vaadin resources as:

**'Fragment-Host: com.vaadin;bundle-version="6.6.6"'**

but that' obviously not a good solution.